# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning is killing me

Tags: pandas, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I try to filter Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ml_data.csv', dtype=str)

def df_filter(df):
    #df = df.copy()

    df.replace('(not set)', '(none)', inplace=True) #comment this and warning will disappear!!!
    df = df[df['device_browser'] != '(none)'] #comment this and warning will disappear!!!

    def browser_filter(s): 
        return ''.join([c for c in s if c.isalpha()])
    df['device_browser'] = df['device_browser'].apply(browser_filter)

    return df

df = df_filter(df)
```

And I receive this warning:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_2185/1710484338.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['device_browser'] = df['device_browser'].apply(browser_filter)
```

But if I uncomment

```
#df = df.copy()
```

OR comment

```
df.replace('(not set)', '(none)', inplace=True)
```

OR comment

```
df = df[df['device_browser'] != '(none)']
```

OR will not wrap filtering in df_filter function

this warning will disappear!!! WHY??????????

I danced around the fire and beat the tambourine...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: NO. Why df = df.copy() removes warning? Or other cases?

Comment: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')  --  I use this to filter out warnings. There is nothing to stop you. There is only a message.

Comment: No, I don't want to suppress the warning, I want to investigate it!

Answer (score 0):

Because by doing `df.copy()` you create a deep copy of our dataframe, you can see that in the documentation, `deep = True` by default.

So if you create a deep copy of your base dataframe, the warning will disappear.

But, if you don't, you will create shallow copy using:`df.replace('(not set)', '(none)', inplace=True)`.
And after you try to filter a shallow copy using `df = df[df['device_browser'] != '(none)']`, that why you have this warning. So if you remove one the two lines, it is logic that you don't have the warning.

I invite you to check the difference between shallow and deep copy on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy%5D).

Comment: OK, but why this warning appears only if execute this code wrapped in df_filter function?

Comment: My intention was to do all filtering inplace, without any copies - deep or shallow.

Comment: Yes you can, but it is good practice to do a copy of the dataframe before modify it anyway. So may be you can start be doing a copy, and after perform your filters. Otherwise, I am sorry, I don't have a better answer.